# Regex date expression not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a javascript function that does some date validation.

```
var regex = new RegExp(my regex expression is here);

var result = regex.test(valueToTest);
```

However, I've been chasing my tail for the last couple of hours because the test always returned false.

```
This does not work
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d\d$

This does not work
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d{2}$

This works
^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$
```

The only difference between the 3 patterns is the final 2 digits. All look perfectly valid but only the 3rd one returns true.

I'm trying to understand if there is anything I've done wrong, or whether there are any issues with the browser (Firefox).

Any ideas?

Comment: Use the native JS `Date` object to validate dates instead of regexps.

Comment: **Always** include test data. Or better yet: a demo (e.g. on jsbin.com)

Comment: did you escape your ``\`` characters for strings?

Comment: @Prinzhorn - I was simply using my birthday - 08/03/1977

Comment: @dotnetnoob Alright. You know, I've never used this date format (other country/locale) and it would just have been nice to have some data I could throw at the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably putting these regexes into a string, in which case the `"\d"` is being translated into a `"d"`.

Try using double slashes: `"\\d"`

However, I must agree with some of the other suggestions - don't use regex for parsing dates. They aren't really well suited for the job.

For example, you expression would allow `'31/02/1985'` which is not a date. In particular, you run into problems with [leap years](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Gregorian_calendar) (which occur every 4 years except for 3 years within a 400 year time span). Try matching that with a regex!

Comment: Dates are tricky things to handle. In some parts of the world they use DD/MM/YYYY, instead of MM/DD/YYYY. That is the reason I always try to use YYYY-MM-DD if possible, it's the only universally understood date format. Don't even get me started on trying to handle timezones...

Comment: @UselessCode - Agreed, although the OP seems to be settled on using a particular, well-defined format.

Comment: thanks, I'm going to use the regex to test for dd/mm/yyyy format but then use javascript for the date.

Comment: @dotnetnoob - If you are using a hybrid approach and just want to ensure that numbers and slashes are there, then you could simplify things significantly by just going with `"^\\d{2}/\\d{2}/\\d{4}$"`

Answer (score 3):

What about a validation without regexps?

```js
function validateDate(string) {
    var parts = string.split("/");
    var year = parseInt(parts[2]);
    var month = parseInt(parts[1]) - 1;
    var day = parseInt(parts[0]);
    var date = new Date(year, month, day);
    return date.getFullYear() === year && date.getMonth() === month && date.getDate() === day;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/abRQZ/)

Comment: +1 Generally a better approach (for reasons outlined in my answer)

Answer (score 1):

If you use the constructor `new RegExp()` you should use the string format :

Example :

```
var regex = new RegExp(my regex expression is here);
var result = regex.test("(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}" ,"ig");
```

but I don't recommend you to use the constructor try to use this:

```
result.match(/^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$/ig);
```

If not what do you want do with your RegExp ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `"\\d"` instead of `"\d"`.

This repros your problem, with test data:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d\d$");
var regex2 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\d{2}$");
var regex3 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$");

document.write("<div>1: "+regex1.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
document.write("<div>2: "+regex2.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
document.write("<div>3: "+regex3.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
```

Output:

```
1: false
2: false
3: true
```

This repros the fix:

```
var regex1 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\\d\\d$");
var regex2 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)\\d{2}$");
var regex3 = new RegExp("^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])/(0[1-9]|1[012])/(19|20)[0-9]{2}$");

document.write("<div>1: "+regex1.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
document.write("<div>2: "+regex2.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
document.write("<div>3: "+regex3.test("22/11/1982")+"</div>");
```

Output:

```
1: true
2: true
3: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping forward slash

Eg : `^(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\/(0[1-9]|1[012])\/(19|20)\d{2}$`

Comment: The second regex seems working for me after escaping forward slash. http://dabblet.com/gist/4732216