# How do I validate a date in this format (dd\mm\yyyy)

Tags: javascript, regex

i have this function:

```
var isValidDate = function (date) {
   var regEx = /^\d{2}\\d{2}\\d{4}$/;
   return date.match(regEx) !== null;
};
```

I want to validate my date with this form :

> 23/01/2015

My question is my REGEX it is good ..?

Comment: It would be best to not to re-invent the wheel here and use a a library such as http://momentjs.com/ which will probably do a better job.

Comment: Don't use regex for date validation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14756200/1225328

Comment: @Magrangs with momentjs when i test moment(date, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid(); is always true

Comment: @Mercer Would that be because the date is valid? Try it with data you know will fail. This is false for example: moment('12/33/2014', 'DD/MM/YYYY').isValid()

Comment: @Magrangs why when i test this moment("29/01/2015564", 'DD/MM/YYYY').isValid(); it's return me TRUE ..?

Comment: @Magrangs moment("23/025/2015", 'DD/MM/YYYY').isValid()
 --> true

Comment: @Mercer You need to turn on strict parsing (the third param true): moment("29/01/2015564", 'DD/MM/YYYY', true).isValid() is false and the other example is also false when strict parsing is set. "Moment's parser is very forgiving, and this can lead to undesired behavior. As of version 2.3.0, you may specify a boolean for the last argument to make Moment use strict parsing. Strict parsing requires that the format and input match exactly." - So ensure you have a version >= 2.3.0 and strict parsing is set to true

Comment: @Mercer You also need to consider the range of date. I mean 11/11/1111 should not be valid. Date between 1900-2099 should be valid. I don't know your requirement, but consider this.

Comment: Try this regular Expression: /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|3[01])\/(19|20)\d{2}$/ and Test here:http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
var regEx = /^\d{2}\\\d{2}\\\d{4}$/;
```

A backslash also requires escaping.

Also note that your original string also needs to have `\\` for a literal backslash like this:

```
var matched = regEx.test('15\\11\\2015')
//=> true
```

For matching `dd/mm/yyyy` regex would be just:

```
var regEx = /^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/;
```

This however would still not invalidate wrong dates like `13/13/2015`

Comment: I think this would be better. It has / instead of \. ^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$

Answer (score 1):

The regex is not safe. Consider `99/99/9999`, an improved regex could read `/^[0-3]\d\/[01]\d\/[12]\d{3}$/. However this still accept dates like`39/19/2999` which is clearly illeagal.

While you can refine your regex further to limit the seperate numbers to valid ranges it becomes rather complex if you want to rule out feb 31. I recommend doing this with actual code rather than a regex.

Answer (score 1):

You may use **html5 pattern** .
  better pattern `^([0-2]\d|3[0-1])\\(0\d|1[0-2])\\[1-2]\d{3}$`  . it will also work in regex..

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^\d{2}\\\d{2}\\\d{4}$" /><br/>
better
<input type="text" pattern="^([0-2]\d|3[0-1])\\(0\d|1[0-2])\\[1-2]\d{3}$" />
```